# Have humans ever used the Log Scale convention in the past rather than the Linear one?

Tags: soft-question, math-history, philosophy

There are many examples where our senses are based off of log scales such as volume of a noise, ability to guess (i.e.) plus or minus a power of 10 with Fermi, and even when we measure pain on 1 to 10 scale most of us subconsciously do it as a log scale. There are even evolutionary advantages such as its much more for survival sake to know the log of a predator. (i.e.) it matters more if theirs 3 vs 1 lions but not if theirs 23 vs 21 lions. Are there any human senses that truly work off of a linear scale to a stimulus? This leads me to wonder the following.

Today we have a convention that is based off of linear scales based off of 1 and successors. From young we are taught linear scales and do everything in school under linear scales. **Has this convention ever been reversed?** It clearly was used for a time with the slide rule but that's more of a way of switching between the two.

Comment: See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weber%E2%80%93Fechner_law

Comment: This would suggest a negative answer to the first question although does not prohibit a positive one. What about the second question?

Comment: This seems more like a question for Biology.SE - whether or not humans have certain properties isn't a math question, per se.

Comment: I'm more interested in the second question anyway which is a math or at the least math history question. I just also wanted to give some background for my question. I will edit to make more clear.

Answer (score 1):

Arguably we think of very large numbers on a log scale.  Once we are past millions, billions, and trillions, we tend to think of a number automatically in terms of the number of digits involved.  This is of course roughly log base 10.

Comment: True but this seems to illustrate my point that it seems intuitive to us but we don't use it.

Comment: Actually we do use it.  This is precisely what Leibniz did when he was working with infinitesimals of different orders.  There is a base infinitesimal, say $dx$, and other useful infinitesimals are expressed in terms of the base one using exponents, like this: $dx^n$. This enables the Leibnizian formalism of writing down derivatives of all orders. Leibniz even experimented with the $d$ procedure of fractional order in a 1710 article, but that's a different story.